# Azure App Services Health Check and security concerns

Tags: azure-web-app-service

My web application's endpoints are all secured and demand an OAuth access token.

To my understanding, Azure App Services Health Check is done through a HTTP call:

https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/08/24/healthcheck-on-app-service.html

Exposing a path like /api/health can be used for attacks like DOS.

How exposing the path /api/health is justified from the security perspective?

What is a secured way of using App Services' Health Check ?

Answer (score 2):

The Azure platform itself does have some mitigations to circumvent DDoS attacks. However, you can add additional layers of protection such as [DDoS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/ddos-protection/#security), [App Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/ag-overview), and [WAF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/afds/waf-front-door-configure-ip-restriction).

Remember though, that if you're using App Service Authentication, the platform will utilize that to send authenticated requests to your configured health check API endpoint. But from a secured way to use health check, you would make sure that your endpoint only accepts [authenticated requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/monitor-instances-health-check?tabs=dotnet#authentication-and-security).

Comment: Thank you for help. When health check accepts authenticated requests, Azure App services health check always receives HTTP 403. Because Azure App services health check  cannot go through sophisticated  OAuth flows. That is why I was hoping not to expose any health check related endpoints and try to track the health of the app service using different measures like checking a file date/content or call a command line.

Comment: Since you've created your own authentication scheme, then yes, your health check API endpoint will have to be anonymous. If you're app service is hosted on Windows though, then you can use the `x-ms-auth-internal-token` header value to verify the request came from health check probe per the link I provided.

Comment: I have the value of `x-ms-auth-internal-token`, but how can I know what value should I set for `WEBSITE_AUTH_ENCRYPTION_KEY`? @RyanHill-MSFT

Comment: So basically - if you use a Linux based app service you're screwed otherwise you have to have a publicly accessible endpoint...?